# Webpack devServer different project loads on Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have this frontend project using Webpack where the devServer is giving me headaches on Chrome: all I see is a project I've worked on about 2 months ago. I'm on Windows 10 - not sure if it matters.

Here is my full webpack.dev.js configuration - it should be nothing too complicated. I cut out the style loaders because it's a lot of lines but they shouldn't be concerned with this problem.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    // here I use contentBase because I need to serve some static files (font-awesome mainly)
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
    host: 'localhost',
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/dist/'
  },
  entry: {
    app: './js/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          }
          //cut for simplicity
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Here is package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.52",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0-beta.52",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.52",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^23.3.0",
    "eslint": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0"
  },
```

So, the problem: when I run `npm start` - which just calls webpack by specifying the config file - the project successfully builds, and the devServer seems to work without any problems.

If I navigate to `localhost:8080` on Firefox, it all works perfectly, but if I navigate to the same location with Chrome, the only thing I can see is a React project (ejected from `create-react-app`) that I was working on about 2-3 months ago.

If I change the target port of the devServer, all is well and it also gets loaded correctly in Chrome, but as soon as I use port 8080, I see the old React project.

The main problem is that I don't really have a way to reproduce this on a different machine.

I know I could just use a different port, but that's not really a solution, it's more of a temporary patch :)

Is there anything in this config that suggests some old code could be loaded, or that it's not clearing down?
Is this some sort of bug with Chrome?

If it's of any use, Chrome has React Developer Tools installed - could that be the culprit?

PS: if anyone wonders, I did close all of the running node instances using Task Manager, and I restarted my machine multiple times over the last few months :)

EDIT: I may have been too fast to say this configuration works on Firefox. It would seem like this is pulling in bundles built with the production script...

EDIT2: added package.json

Comment: have you tried clearing Chrome's cache?

Comment: @Guillaume yes I've done CTRL+F5 several times - also Chrome is set to clear cache whenever devtools are open

Comment: can you show the devserver script?

Comment: @Guillaume I'm only using webpack 4 base functionalities for the devServer, so I'm not directly calling webpack-dev-server - if you're looking for the npm script, it's `"start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js"` - added package.json to the question